# MOD_PROXY with Squid

Tags: webserver, cache, squid, http-proxy

I am not entirely sure how to ask this question so it may have been discussed before. Attached below is an image of my image server setup. Here is how it works:

1. A User visits my real estate website that hosts properties from all over the country.
2. Each section of the website uses a specific image server to deliver images based on the state that the property is located in
3. I have a mod_proxy server running that directs requests for images to the appropriate image server on my local network.

Everything is working now and the images are being served as expected fairly efficiently. What I am after is possibly caching some of the most viewed images so that content is loaded faster than it currently is. I know that squid is a caching system and I was thinking about integrating it into my network to deliver cached images if they exists, and if they don't exist in cache it should call the appropriate image server for the content.

I am not sure exactly where the squid installation should reside however, should that be installed on the mod_proxy server or on the individual image servers?

Any recommendations to my setup would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Network Diagram]